# Fastboot Xiaomi system partition problem

Tags: twrp, fastboot, system, xiaomi

I am trying to upgrade Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite to Android Pie via fastboot ROM images. It was on Oreo, initially. Had TWRP

installed in boot.img because it is an A/B slots device. TWRP is officially supported.
Had made a full TWRP backup, also system_image and vendor_image, which are exact copies of the whole system. Then

tried official Xiaomi fastboot Pie images, and system.img doesn't flash. Other smaller in size system images I flashed to see

what would happen do go through, but they don't work. Pie image is 2.1 GB. Other partitions are all flashed.
Each attempt via Xiaomi flash tool ends with: Chunk data size exceeds partition size.
Log:
$fastboot -s 08f97d930705 flash system_a C:\XiaoMi\XiaoMiFlash\Source\ThirdParty\Google\Android

\daisy_global_images_V10.0.10.0.PDLMIXM_9.0\images\system.img   || 
10:26:06 AM  08f97d930705:target reported max download size of 534773760 bytes
10:26:06 AM  08f97d930705:sending sparse 'system_a' 1/3 (462332 KB)...
10:26:06 AM  08f97d930705:OKAY  59.062s:writing 'system_a' 1/3...
10:26:06 AM  08f97d930705:flashSuccess False

Fastboot flash_all.bat gives:
fastboot  getvar product   2>&1  | findstr /r /c:"^product: *d
aisy"   ||
The system cannot find message text for message number 0x8 in the message file f
or System.

Fastboot flash system sends sparse chunks and gives:
data too large

So, what gives? Any ideas greatly appreciated. Oh, TWRP boots, but can't use touchscreen at all, no response

whatsoever, can't restore my perfect Oreo backup, and wanted to go to Pie and cutom ROMs anyway.
If anybody can shed some light, I will be grateful.

Also tried flashing different boot images from Pie and Oreo and different TWRP versions than the latest, nothing works.

Comment: this should help regarding touchscreen. for system you can convert to ext4 image and then adb push https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Comment: Thanks alecxs. TWRP commands helped me restore. Greatly appreciated.